# Print all stored proc variables (Firebird)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

I have an stored procedure that get executed after insert and update. I need to print all  variables values but only when user press on a print button (user request)

In theory what is the best way to return variable values ? I use Delphi.

thanks

Comment: What "get executed after insert or update" means? Is the procedure called from triggers? How do you want variables values be printed?

Comment: I dont want to print after execute from trigger we can use a button the problem I have 16 variables do I must return all as output parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to return some values from SP:

1) make selectable SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_sp
  RETURNS (A INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  A = 1;
  SUSPEND;
END
```

Note usage of SUSPEND keyword. You can access return values of selectable procedure using regular SELECT operator:

```
SELECT * FROM select_sp
```

2) make executable SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE exec_sp
  RETURNS (A INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  A = 1;
END
```

Then you need TIBStoredProc component in your Delphi code in order to invoke the procedure and gets its return parameters. Use ParamByName method.